# Sobolev seminorm related to affine mapping

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

the context of my question is finite element theory here, but my question is purely mathematical. Let $F$ be an affine mapping from a reference triangle $\hat{T}$ to a general triangle $T$, call it $F:\hat{T} \rightarrow{T}$ which has the form $$F(\hat{x})=B \hat{x} +b$$ for some matrix $B$ which maps a reference triangle $(0,0)$,$(1,0)$,$(0,1)$ into a general triangle $T$. This framework is classical in finite element books.

Let us consider a function $\hat{f} : \hat{T} \rightarrow R$, and a function $v$ defined as $$f = \hat{f} \circ F^{-1} $$

Equivalently, $\hat{f} = f \circ F$.  We have the following [image] (see [here at page 63](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Earnold//8445-8446.14-15/notes.pdf) for the lecture notes)

**Question:** I honestly can't understand how to get formula (4.7). I can obtain easily the formula before (4.7). In particular, I don't know how the term $\sum_i \sum_k b_{ij} b_{kl}$ can be bounded with the norm of $B$. I don't see how to make a norm appear from there. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can choose any matrix norm you want, because they are equivalent.  Maybe choose $\lVert B \rVert := \sup_{i, j} \lvert B_{ij} \rvert$. Just make a convenient choice

Comment: So, for instance in the example above, you have $\sum_i \sum_k b_{ij} b_{kl} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_k} \leq ||B||^2 \sum_i \sum_k \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}$, right? @Meowdog

Comment: Almost. It is $\left \lvert \displaystyle \sum_i \sum_k b_{ij}b_{kl} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_k }\right \rvert \leq \lVert B^2 \rVert  \sum_i \sum_k \left \lvert\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_k }\right \rvert$

Comment: Yes sure. So to get the $||B||^r$ in (4.7) you have to sum over all possible combinations of multiindices $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=r$, then you factor out the term $||B||^r$, which will multiply precisely $\sum_{|\beta|=r} |D^\beta f(x)|$, right @Meowdog

Comment: yes that's correct, the constant $c$ in the inequality is dependent on $r$ and the spatial dimension.